# why is angularjs controller undefined when its requested second time

Tags: angularjs

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <test>
        <test-sub>nop</test-sub>
    </test>
</div>
```

js:

```
var m = angular.module('myApp', []);

m.directive('test', ['$compile', function(_compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: ["$scope", function(_scope) {
            _scope.testItems = [];
            this.addItem = function(_obj) {
                _scope.testItems.push(_obj);
                console.log('addItem');
                console.log(_obj)
            }
        }],
        link: function(_scope, _element, _attrs, _controller) {
            console.log('--- test -------------------');
            var tmpl = "<test-sub>yep</test-sub>";
            // var tmplCompiled = _compile(tmpl)(_scope);
            _element.replaceWith(_compile(tmpl)(_scope));
        }
    }
}]);

m.directive('testSub', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^?test',
        controller: ["$scope", function(_scope) {
        }],
        link: function(_scope, _element, _attrs, _controller) {
            console.log('--- testSub ----------------');
            _controller.addItem({x1:'x1',y1:'y1'});
        }
    }
}]);
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/isnigirev/KF34m/ )

I got:

```
--- testSub ---------------- (index):54
addItem (index):34
Object {x1: "x1", y1: "y1"} (index):35
--- test ------------------- (index):39
--- testSub ---------------- (index):54
TypeError: Cannot call method 'addItem' of undefined

or in FireFox console:

--- testSub ----------------
test_r...03.html (line 49)
addItem
test_r...03.html (line 29)
Object { x1="x1", y1="y1"}
test_r...03.html (line 30)
--- test -------------------
test_r...03.html (line 34)
--- testSub ----------------
test_r...03.html (line 49)

Error: _controller is undefined
.link@(~skipped~).html:50
```

Questions:
 1. why "addItem" is called twice? (how to prevent calling it second time)
 2. why is controller undefined when it's requested second time? (it's even MORE interesting!)

Answer (score 0):

The first time 'addItem' is called is when the first 'testSub' is linked. The second time is when you compile the 'test' to be 'testSub' within the 'test' link:

```
var tmpl = "<test-sub>yep</test-sub>";
_element.replaceWith(_compile(tmpl)(_scope));
```

The test is no longer exists and there is no 'addItem'. thus the controller is undefined.

What was your intention by doing that? you may do it another way . . .

Comment: What do you mean by another way? I'm using "$compile" because i need to change applyed template depending on some conditions.

Comment: You can use attach a controller to the div and implement the 'addItem' there.

Comment: "The test is no longer exists" - the same error occured even without "_element.replaceWith..." (just with var tmplCompiled = _compile(tmpl)(_scope) ).